# Back button with react-jsonschema-form lib

Tags: javascript, json, forms, reactjs

Using this library let's me write forms in json schema with react ( I needed that for a better control and view of my forms for my dynamic needs) I want to implement a back button that will get me from the current form to the previous one, here is the documentation: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form , I didn't found anything related to that my problem.

For testing I will give this js fiddle example that is similar to my case:

https://jsfiddle.net/sn4bnw9h/1/

```js
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "react-jsonschema-form demo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["name"],
  properties: {
   name: {type: "string", minLength: 3},
    description: {type: "string"}
  }
};
const uiSchema = {
  description: {
    "ui:widget": "textarea"
  }
};

function Tpl(props) {
  const {id, classNames, label, help, required, description, rawErrors=[], children} = props;
  return (
    <div className={classNames}>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}{required ? "*" : null}</label>
      {description}
      {children}
      {rawErrors.map(error => <div style={{color: "blue"}}><h1>{error}</h1></div>)}
      {help}
    </div>
  );
}

React.render(<Form schema={schema} uiSchema={uiSchema} FieldTemplate={Tpl} liveValidate/>, 
             document.getElementById("main"));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

My desired output should be: implementing there a back button that will get you after submit from step 2 back to step 1 when back is pressed. 
It can be added some uiSchema, but I don't know exactly what to use. I had tryed with `backButton: {type: "button", title: 'Back'}` but it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can control the buttons that appear at the bottom of your react-jsonschema-form by adding children to the  component. Insert a back button with a corresponding `onClick` function.

```
 <Form 
    schema={this.state.step === 1 ? step1schema : step2schema}
    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
    formData={this.state.formData}>
    { this.state.step > 1 &&
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleBack} className="btn btn-secondary">Back</button>
    }
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</Form>
```

A working version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdz6p5y/